# $\sup_{x,y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} = \sup_x \|D_f(x)\|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open ball, $f:B \to \mathbb R^n$ differentiable.

Show that $\sup_{x,y \in B, x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} = \sup_{x \in B}\|D_f(x)\|$

What I did:

$\sup_{x \in B}\|D_f(x)\| = \sup_{x \in B} \sup_{|v| = 1}|D_f(x)v| = \sup_{x \in B, |v| = 1}|D_f(x)v| = \sup_{x \in B, |v|=1} |\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}| = \sup_{x \in B, |v|=1} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|f(x+tv)-f(x)|}{|t|}$

And here I am stuck.

If we could somehow magically get rid of the limit, we would be left with something that looks a lot like what we want to show, but how do we do that?

Comment: I think you should try showing this equality by showing both inequalities.  First, given $a = sup_{x \in B}||D_f(x)||$ can you show  that the other quantity is at least $a$?  I think that's the way that's closer to the definition.  For the opposite inequality... have you seen the mean value theorem?

Comment: @TimCarson If we could use the MVT then it would also show that the operator norm of the differential is greater, so it's not the other way. But regardless, there is no MVT form for vector valued functions.

Comment: Reading my comment again the ellipses made it come off as a smug "this should be clear if you have" but i certainly didnt mean that :) The trick posted in an answer is what i had in mind.

Comment: @Oria Gruber: Yet, there are some MVT's for vector-valued functions.  See C. C. Pugh, _Real Mathematical Analysis_, Springer, 2002, in particular Theorems 11 and 12 on pp. 277-278 and Exercise 17 (b) on p. 348.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality 
$$
\sup\limits_{x, y \in B,\ x \ne y} \frac{\lvert f(x) - f(y) \lvert}{\lvert x - y\rvert} \le \sup\limits_{x \in B}\, \lVert D_f(x) \rVert
$$
follows from (indeed, is almost the precise statement) of Theorem 11 on p. 277 of:  C. C. Pugh, *Real Mathematical Analysis*, Springer, 2002 (the proof rests on an application of the one-dimensional MVT to the function $g(t) = \langle u, f(y + t (x - y) \rangle$, where $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is any unit vector).

The second inequality is straightforward.

Comment: Could you give more hints on the converse inequality? I can't see the way.

Comment: Fix $x\in B$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lvert v\rvert=1$. In the last term of the OP's display the limit as $t\to0$ of the difference quotient is $\le$ the supremum of the difference quotient over all $t\ne0$ such that $x+tv\in B$. Now, if you take the supremum of the resulting expression over all $x\in B$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lvert v\rvert=1$ you obtain the supremum of $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert/\lvert x-y\rvert$ over all pairs $(x,y)\in B\times B$ with $x\ne y$